# LLVM: implement safe multi-instance environment inside a program

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, llvm

I'm a beginner with LLVM, but not with programming itself. And for one of my projects I need a safe multi-instance environment. For which I choose LLVM. I googled for a week and found nothing.

So, that's my question: is it possible to run multiple ExecutionEngine's with the same bitcode loaded into and continue running even after NULL pointer dereference or something similar (which cause SIGSEGV in normal situation) happened in VM.

For example:

1) create a simple program with a problem inside

`int* p = NULL;
*p++;`

2) compile it to bitcode

`$ clang -c -emit-llvm -o null.bc null.c`

3) run it inside other program (something like

`LLVMContext context;
    string error;
    Module *m = ParseBitcodeFile(MemoryBuffer::getFile("null.bc"), context, &error);
    ExecutionEngine *ee = ExecutionEngine::create(m);
    Function* func = ee->FindFunctionNamed("main");
    typedef void (*PFN)();
    PFN pfn = reinterpret_cast<PFN>(ee->getPointerToFunction(func));
    pfn();`
)

4) catch an exception (obviously SIGSEGV), but DON't crash the main program.

Is it possible with Interpreter? Or with JIT? (MCJIT obviously won't work)

And again, it should be possible to run many instances (in separate threads) of bitcode.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Doable? To some degree. You could set up a signal handler for SIGSEGV and kill off the offending thread there and ignore the error.

But is that bulletproof (not to speak of a good idea)? Nope. The programs you're running are obviously buggy or malicious - you cannot know what else they screwed up before they finally caused a SIGSEV or other error. Hence any error handling code you wrote in the same process could have been overwritten by the malicious program and you can't do much about that.

You should do what everybody else does these days when executing untrusted, buggy code (major example being the browser vendors): Run everything in its own process and use interprocess communication. That separates your trusted code from the untrusted one.

Comment: I merely sure that code (running in VM) isn't malicious, because it's written by me. But I can't be sure it is bugless. And obviously SIGSEGV won't be a single signal to be catched.

Comment: @user The basic problem is the same whether you have malicious or just plain old buggy code, malicious code is just more likely to exploit it in interesting new ways.

Comment: So, LLVM can't be used to solve such a pseudo-sandbox problem?

Comment: **Nothing** can be used to solve this problem for native code (sandboxing semi-works for the JVM if you discount malicious code). As soon as you can write to arbitrary memory locations in your process you've lost. If there was any sensible general solution for this problem not every browser vendor would've gone for out-of-process plugin architectures.

Comment: OK, I understand. But may it still can be usable to make many instances of the same code (none of which will use any remarkable system resource, such as filesystem IO or similar) in separated threads?